# New Kernel does not automatically reconnect to network

Tags: networking, kernel

I tried playing around with compiling my own kernel. Everything is fine so far, except for that one thing.

Whenever I leave a wifi network or unplug my ethernet cable the system does not recognize, that the connection was lost and I have to manually tell the network manager.

I think it has to do with the new kernel, since that is the only thing that changed.

Since I feel like the documentation on the kernel components is pretty hard to parse, I'll ask it:

What kernel module/symbol did I set wrongly to provoke this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My particular problem turned out to be `ifplugd`. It failed with a `NLAPI: Packet too small or truncated` error everytime I plugged my ethernet cable in or out.

Seems like some change in Kernel 3.9 introduced something. So I recompiled `ifplugd` with a change to the buffer size in `src/nlapi.c` line 74.

```
-- char replybuf[1024];
++ char replybuf[8*1024];
```

Now it works.

Related links:

- [Bug Report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=704495)
- [Fix in busybox version of ifplugd](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/busybox/networking/ifplugd.c#456)

Comment: Have you filed a bug?

Comment: The bug is already filed here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=704495 The code seems to have changed since then without fixing the problem, that's why I omitted the link, but for completeness sake, it should be there.